# can docmd.gotorecord,,acnew open in new window?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a form which is bound to a table, and lets a user scroll through existing records in the table and make changes. I'm now trying to build a button which allows the user to insert a new record. So far I have a button with some basic vba:

```
Private Sub btnNew_Click()

DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acNewRec

End Sub
```

This opens a new record in the same form and has no way of assuring a user that the record has been saved. What i would really like is for the this to open a new 'pop up'form with a save button on

how would i do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to the design view of the Form, add a button name it **saveBtn**. Under its properties, set the visibility as **No**. Now in the **Form Current** method, check if the form has the new record, if so make the button visible.

```
Private Sub Form_Current()
    Me.saveBtn.Visible = Me.NewRecord
End Sub
```

Using this method, the current form could be used for navigation and editing and when it sits on a new record a Save button will be available where in you could add the code to run a Save command or close the Form, which by default will save the record.